# SQL Image to Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I want to pull image data from SQL Server 2008 Express and display it directly in a Crystal Report. I am using Visual Studio 2012 along with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio (also a full version of SAP Crystal Reports 2013).

I have attempted to use samples from Google/SO searches but I seem to be missing at least one key element. In my project I have a dataset with one field which is of `System.Byte()`, a Crystal Report, and a viewer.

Here is the snippet of code which queries the database, reads the memorystream, and puts the image data into the dataset.

```
 Dim ds As New DataSet1
   Dim row As DataRow

   Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection.CTLDataConnectionString)
   Dim objCommand As SqlCommand = objConn.CreateCommand
   objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Content FROM Report WHERE HandlingUnitID = " & HandlingUID
   Dim dr As SqlDataReader = Nothing
   If objConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then objConn.Open()

   dr = objCommand.ExecuteReader

   If dr.HasRows Then
       dr.Read()
       Dim b() As Byte = DirectCast(dr("Content"), Byte())
       Using ms As New MemoryStream(b)
         ds.DataTable1.Rows.Add(b)
       End Using

   End If

   Dim rpt As New ShipLabel
   rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables("DataTable1"))

   Dim frm As New CRviewer
   frm.CRvwr.ReportSource = rpt
   frm.ShowDialog()
```

This will bring up the Crystal Viewer but it is a blank report. I want to know if I have the correct sequence for getting the data, and if I am storing it correctly in the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more reading/researching I have the following snippets of code which appear to have the correct sequencing, and correctly storing the data in the dataset. This snippet is from a cellclick event.

```
 Dim ds As New DataSet1
   Dim row As DataRow

   Dim img As Bitmap

   Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection.CTLDataConnectionString)
   Dim objCommand As SqlCommand = objConn.CreateCommand
   objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Content FROM Report WHERE HandlingUnitID = " & HandlingUID
   Dim dr As SqlDataReader = Nothing
   If objConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then objConn.Open()

   dr = objCommand.ExecuteReader

   If dr.HasRows Then
       dr.Read()
       Dim b() As Byte = dr("Content")

    Using ms As New MemoryStream(b)
        img = Image.FromStream(ms)
        b = ConvertImageToByte(img)
        ds.DataTable1.Rows.Add(b)
    End Using

   End If
   objConn.Close()

   Dim rpt As New ShipLabel
   rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables("DataTable1"))
   rpt.SetParameterValue("JobNumber", OrderNumber.ToString)

   Dim frm As New CRviewer
   frm.CRvwr.ReportSource = rpt
   frm.ShowDialog()
```

And this function:

```
Public Shared Function ConvertImageToByte(ByVal Value As Image) As Byte()
If Value IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim fs As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    CType(Value, Bitmap).Save(fs, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim retval As Byte() = fs.ToArray()
    fs.Dispose()
    Return retval
End If

Return Nothing
```

End Function